# openssl how can I create a self-contained signed file?

Tags: openssh

I'd like to use openssh to sign a file, and then pack

1. the file
2. the public key
3. the signature hash

Into **one** self-contained file. In a container file like pem. Oh, and I understand that what will be signed and verifiable is the **file**, not the self-contained thingie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I can. All I have to do to is

1. Sign the file
2. Put the public key in the file
3. Put the hash in the file

You can add info like this to all kinds of file types.
Your file can also be an archive itself, in witch case the problem is solved.

To verify the file, first extract (in the proper sense of the term : Read then erase) the hash and the key, *then* verify.

Comment: What do you mean by "put ... in the file" and "erase"? The adding of the key and the hash has to be exactly reversed by removing them. The point of a formal format like PEM is that it makes this possible, and lets a program do it. If you don't have a formal format, then there is a risk of getting it wrong, and having spurious signature failures. It's not clear to me that your answer actually solves your question!